# Hide folders with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory

Is it possible to hide the folders in my root folder?
Just in case my index.php would disappear you know?

Could I also show 404 error not found if someone requests them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
IndexIgnore *
```

The above would prevent all files from being listed. Here `*` acts as a wildcard. You could replace it with something more specific, if needed.

Comment: replace `*` how? Let's say I have 3 files and 1 folder I want to hide (`file1.jpg, some.pdf, else.html, i-am-a-folder`)

Comment: IndexIgnore doesn't disallow access to known file locations within the folder that it protects.

An htaccess with:
    `order allow,deny`
    `deny from all`
would do a better job.

Answer (score 42):

What you want is probably

```
Options -Indexes
```

which will just give a 404 error if no DirectoryIndex file is found.

Comment: I think it’s rather a 403.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by duskwuff, what you need is

```
Options - Indexes
```

This will cause a 403 forbidden error on that particular directory. Thus to provide a custom error page you will need

```
ErrorDocument   403 myErrorPage.html
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer was 5 hours to late, but should be the accepted answer. This will with no index file produce an error, that you can then handle or use the default server one. The accepted answer will simple hide the folders in the directory view page. So it produces a false positive.. Old post but in top google results.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to show a 404 error for subfolder(s) , try the following in `/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

If an existent `/folder` or `/subfolder` is requested, the above rule will rewrite it to `/404` .

Answer (score 2):

I get around this by adding an index.html on all folders i dont want accessed. The index.html page contains a single line with the following `header("Location:thepageiwanttoshown.html")`. This way if the user accidentally visits the restricted folders they will be redirected on the fly. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This was my preferred solution to the same problem (this displays an Access Denied instead of 404 though):

```
<files "/path/to/single/file/or/folder">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</files>
```

This also gives you the option to give access to certain IP's (in this case it deny's access to all)

The "/path/to/single/file/or/folder" can be replaced with regex if you want to use a pattern instead. Otherwise you have to use multiple blocks for each specific file or folder that you want to block access to.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i did that but it shows me Error 500. This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options - Indexes
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me it always works with adding

```
<Directory "/var/www/yourfolder"> IndexIgnore * </Directory>
```

to the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

At your main root .htaccess put the flowing code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dfjgekbjvrskzcnfvberidurvf/?(.*)$    /folder1/$1 [L]


Then at .htaccess file in folder1 directory put this :

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !dfjgekbjvrskzcnfvberidurvf
RewriteRule ^    - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

make a file mame .htaccess in the directory where you want to hide folder's list and just this code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```