# " index of/ " problem after wordpress installation and and importing my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting, addon-domain

i recently decided to host my new wordpress site on the same shared hosting account as my other site, so i created an addon domain and installed wordpress on it. I also used all-in-1 wordpress migration plugin to export my wordpress site from my the wordpress installation on my local server. I used the same plugin to import my wordpress site into the wordpress on my shared hosting account. Now the challenge is, when i try to visit the address of the addon domain, the server serves up a page showing a directory of all the files in the addon domain directory. I have tried solving the issue myself and asking people but what i hear is that i should add an index.php file, but the file is already there. Please if you have experienced this problem before, how were you able to resolve it?

the wordpress version for both the the local and live installation is 5.0.4. the all-in-one wordpress migration version for both cases is the latest version.

here is a link to the a screenshot of the page. maybe there is a file i need to manually add.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A-xYnI3bZVlqeF_vlWQgj7mnRxQ-8lch

## **UPDATE**

i was going through error logs on the cpanel error metric and found that a new error log is created everytime i reload the site.
the error always says:

```
[Mon Jun 17 03:31:06.939849 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 4513:tid 47727821616896] [client 197.210.53.253:9715] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/commehub/public_html/my_addon_domain.com.ng/error_log
```

maybe this could help

Comment: Please following the related link, that will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382186/hide-folders-with-htaccess#1382386

Comment: Please check the public_html directory for any hidden files like .htaccess. If its present, try and rename it to _.htaccess.original_ to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Okk. Leme try it

Comment: Thanks @HarijithR  , it worked, what it did was point me in the right direction. when i changed the root **.htaccess** file to **.htaccess.original**, the addon-domain worked, but my main domain default index page changed since i was overriding the **index.php** to **indexlaunch.php**. So that got me thinking, after reading a few articles, i realised it's necessary i specifically set the default index page of my addon domain to **index.php** since it inherited what was set in the root .htaccess file. basically what i did was to put `DirectoryIndex index.php` in addon domain .htaccess file

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. Take care.